# How do I get arrays mapped in a row in google sheet using JavaScript/Google App script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, mapping

I have a code that reads two columns (D & H) in multiple sheets and saves them in the array. What I would like to do is to have the data in this array mapped into one row in a stagging sheet but I keep running to an error:  running into an error **The parameters (number,number,number,null) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRangeList.** I really every time the sheets are read the data should be appended to the next row. I will appreciate any help in solving the challenge

```
function combinesheets() {
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById( Copy_Folder_id)
var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();

var file;
var fileType;
var ssID;
var combinedData = [];
var data;

while(filesIterator.hasNext()){
 file = filesIterator.next();
 fileType = file.getMimeType();

if(fileType === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
ssID = file.getId()
data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID);
combinedData = combinedData.concat(data);
} //if ends here

}//while ends here

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Stage_sheet_id);
var ss = ws.getSheetByName("Project List");
ws.getRangeList(2,1, combinedData.length, combinedData.length [0]).setValues(combinedData) //running into an error on this line- The parameters (number,number,number,null) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRangeList.
Logger.log(combinedData)

}

function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID){
var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
var ws = ss.getSheets()[0]
var data =  ws.getRange("A11:I" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();// how do I get the columns I want here (D & H)
Logger.log(data)

}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Why do you have DriveApp code there if it has nothing to do with the question? Or is there a part of the question that I am missing? Also, I am not sure I understand the column mapping idea, can you post a sample of the source data and the expected output? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because the `getDataFromSpreadsheet()` function does not `return` its result.

To get the values in columns D and H, omitting blank rows, try this:

```
const values1 = ws.getRange('D11:D').getValues();
const values2 = ws.getRange('H11:H').getValues();
return values1.map((row, index) => row.concat(values2[index]))
  .filter(row => row.join(''));
```

In `combinesheets()`, store the data with this:

```
ss.getRange(2, 1, combinedData.length, combinedData[0].length)
  .setValues(combinedData);
```

Comment: Thanks for you respponse doubleunary. When I edit the code using your suggestion, I now run to another error TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Edited the answer to get and return the values properly in `getDataFromSpreadsheet()`.